# Macro compiler error: "Parse Issue" when an argument name appears elsewhere

Tags: objective-c, macros, preprocessor-directive

I tried making a straightforward macro for creating and showing a simple "ok" dialog box in iOS:

```
#define ALERT_DIALOG(title,message) \
do\
{\
    UIAlertView *alert_Dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(title) message:(message) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];\
    [alert_Dialog show];\
} while ( 0 )
```

If I try to use it in my code:

```
ALERT_DIALOG(@"Warning", @"Message");
```

I get the error:

> Parse Issue.  Expected ']'

And the error seems to be pointing at the second `@` right before `"Message"`.

However, if I simply copy paste the macro I do not get this error:

```
NSString *title = @"Warning";
NSString *message = @"Message";
do
{
    UIAlertView *alert_Dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(title) message:(message) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert_Dialog show];
} while ( 0 );
```

Is there something against using Objective-c constructs in macros? Or is that something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your macro is that ***both occurrences*** of `message` in

```
... [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(title) message:(message) ...
```

are replaced by `@"Message"`, resulting in

```
.... [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(@"Warning") @"Message":(@"Message") ...
```

and that causes the syntax error.

I don't think that it is really worth defining this as a macro, but if you do, you have to use macro arguments which do not occur at places where they should not be expanded, e.g.

```
#define ALERT_DIALOG(__title__,__message__) \
do\
{\
    UIAlertView *alert_Dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(__title__) message:(__message__) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];\
    [alert_Dialog show];\
} while ( 0 )
```

or similar.

Comment: Ah, HA! I knew it was something stupid...there was no reason for that macro to not be able to work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring it as a macro, you can declare it as a C function instead:

```
void ALERT_DIALOG(NSString *title, NSString *message) {
    UIAlertView *alert_Dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(title) message:(message) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];\
    [alert_Dialog show];
}
```

Comment: True, gets the job done just as good, but what if I really cared about that stack overhead?